# Не могу получить даные через JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Начал изучать туториал, который якобы позволяет изучить JQuery в связке с PHP + MySQL. Но увы, код оказался не очень работоспособным. Данные отправляются в PHP и получаются из MySQL, а вот обратно не приходят.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="img/3.jpg" width="70px">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <span class="name">Jamie Vardy</span> <span class="date"> 14:15 22.04.2016 </span>

                <div class="text">
                    Some text was here <span class="hashtag">#share</span> <span class="hashtag">#repost</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Код JQuery:**

```
function addNewPost(name, text, date) {
        var newPost = $("#posts").find("div:eq(0)").clone();
        newPost.find('.text').text(text);
        newPost.find('.name').text(name);
        newPost.find('.date').text(date);

        var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        newPost.find('img').attr('src', 'img/' + random + '.jpg');

        return newPost;
    }

function loadAllPost() {
        var divs  = $("#posts");

        $.get("twitor.php?action=last", function() {
            var posts = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                var newPost = addNewPost(posts[i].name, posts[i].text, posts[i].date);
                posts.push(newPost);
            }
            divs.children().remove();
            divs.append(posts);
        });

    }


    $(function() {
        loadAllPost();
        setInterval(loadAllPost, 5000);
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var newPostName = $("#name").val();
            var newPostText = $("#text").val();
            var newPostDate = (new Date()).toLocaleString();
            var newPost = addNewPost(newPostName, newPostText, newPostDate);
            newPost.hide();
            $("#posts").append(newPost);
            newPost.slideToggle();

            $("name").val("");
            $("text").val("");

            $.post("twitor.php?action=new", {
                text: newPostText,
                name: newPostName
            });
        });
    });
```

Данные отправляются в PHP скрипт, заносятся в БД и извлекаются в рамках MYSQL, а вот забора данных в JQuery для последующего вывода в HTML - нет.

**Код PHP:**

```
        if ($_GET['action'] == 'new') {
        addNewPost();
    }
    elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'last') {
        getLastPosts();
    }

    function getPDO(){
        $db_host = "****";
        $db_name = "****";
        $db_user = "****";
        $db_pass = "****";
        $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
        //$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
        return $PDO;
    }

    function addNewPost(){
        $params = [];
        $params['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $params['text'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
        $PDO = getPDO();
        $Statement = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(`name`, `text`, `date`) VALUES (:name, :text, NOW());");
        $Statement->execute($params);
    }

    function getLastPosts() {
        $PDO = getPDO();
        $Statement = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 15");
        if(!$Statement) return;
        $posts = $Statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($posts);
    }
```

**LOG:**

```
[{"id":"61","name":"454","text":"454545","date":"2016-04-22 18:14:34"},{"id":"60","name":"we3r3","text":"rfeef","date":"2016-04-22 17:08:47"},{"id":"59","name":"\u0414\u0436\u043e\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043d \u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441 ","text":"Jamie Vardy, \u0437\u0430 \u0441\u0443\u043a\u0443 \u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0438\u0448\u044c!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!","date":"2016-04-22 16:11:45"},{"id":"58","name":"Jamie Vardy ","text":"\u0414\u0436\u043e\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043d \u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441, \u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e \u043d\u0435 \u0437\u043d\u0430\u044e \u043f\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043c\u0443 \u0442\u044b \u0442\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043a\u043e\u043d\u0447\u0435\u043d\u044b\u0439 #\u0441\u0443\u0434\u044c\u044f\u0433\u0435\u0439 #\u0440\u0435\u043f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043b\u0438\u0443\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438","date":"2016-04-22 16:10:05"},{"id":"57","name":"\u0414\u0436\u043e\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043d \u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441","text":"Jamie Vardy, \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u0442\u044b \u0447\u043e \u043e\u0445##\u0435\u043b? ","date":"2016-04-22 16:03:59"},{"id":"41","name":"\u0414\u0436\u043e\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043d \u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441","text":"Vardi, \u0437\u0430 \u0441\u0443\u043a\u0443 - \u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0438\u0448\u044c! #lol #redcard","date":"2016-04-22 15:08:19"},{"id":"40","name":"Jamie Vardy ","text":"\u0414\u0436\u043e\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043d \u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441, \u0442\u044b \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e \u0443\u043f\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0442, \u0447\u0443\u0432\u0430\u043a! ","date":"2016-04-22 15:06:23"},{"id":"39","name":"\u0414\u0436\u043e\u043d\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043d \u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441","text":"Vardi, \u0430 \u044f \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043b \u0441\u0438\u0442\u0443\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044e \u0442\u0430\u043a.","date":"2016-04-22 15:05:19"},{"id":"38","name":"\u0421\u0443\u0434\u044c\u044f","text":"Vardi, \u0430 \u044f \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043b \u0441\u0438\u0442\u0443\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044e \u0442\u0430\u043a.","date":"2016-04-22 15:04:39"},{"id":"37","name":"\u0421\u0443\u0434\u044c\u044f","text":"&lt;b&gt;Vardi&lt;\/b&gt;, \u0430 \u044f \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043b \u0441\u0438\u0442\u0443\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044e \u0442\u0430\u043a. ","date":"2016-04-22 14:59:07"},{"id":"36","name":"Vardi","text":"@\u0421\u0443\u0434\u044c\u044f, \u0442\u044b \u0442\u0432\u0430\u0440\u044c \u0432\u0441\u0435 \u0436\u0435! ","date":"2016-04-22 14:51:35"},{"id":"35","name":"\u0421\u0443\u0434\u044c\u044f","text":"\u0412\u0430\u0440\u0434\u0438, \u0430 \u044f \u0442\u0443\u0442 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0447\u0435\u043c? ","date":"2016-04-22 14:51:10"},{"id":"34","name":"Vardi","text":"\u0417\u0410 \u0427\u0422\u041e \u0421\u0423\u0414\u042c\u042f? \u0422\u0412\u0410\u0420\u042c!","date":"2016-04-22 14:50:55"},{"id":"33","name":"Sasha","text":"FU MATE!","date":"2016-04-22 14:50:27"},{"id":"32","name":"\u0412\u0438\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440","text":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043a\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u044b #\u044f\u0441\u043b\u0438\u0448\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0448\u0438\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0435\u043d ","date":"2016-04-22 14:45:37"}]array(1) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(4) "last"
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btnRefresh").click(function(){
    
    var divs  = $("#posts");
    
    var dataString = "[{\"id\":\"61\",\"name\":\"454\",\"text\":\"454545\",\"date\":\"2016-04-22 18:14:34\"},{\"id\":\"60\",\"name\":\"we3r3\",\"text\":\"rfeef\",\"date\":\"2016‌​-04-22 17:08:47\"},{\"id\":\"59\",\"name\":\"\\u0414\\u0436\\u043e\\u043d\\u0430\\u0442\\u0430‌​\\u043d \\u041c\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441 \",\"text\":\"Jamie Vardy, \\u0437\\u0430 \\u0441\\u0443\\u043a\\u0443 \\u043e\\u0442\\u0432\\u0435\\u0442\\u0438\\u0448\\u044c!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!‌​!!\",\"date\":\"2016-04-22 16:11:45\"}]";
    /*var data = [
      { name: "John", text: "I am a carpenter", date: new Date() },
      { name: "Mary", text: "I have a little lamb", date: new Date() }
    ];*/
    var data = JSON.parse(dataString);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    var posts = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var newPost = addNewPost(data[i].name, data[i].text, data[i].date);
       posts.push(newPost);
    }
    divs.children().remove();
    divs.append(posts);
  });
  
});

function addNewPost(name, text, date) {

  var newPost = $("#posts").find("div:eq(0)").clone();
  newPost.find('.text').text(text);
  newPost.find('.name').text(name);
  newPost.find('.date').text(date);

  var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
  newPost.find('img').attr('src', 'img/' + random + '.jpg');

  return newPost;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="posts">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="img/3.jpg" width="70px">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <span class="name">Jamie Vardy</span> <span class="date"> 14:15 22.04.2016 </span>

                <div class="text">
                    Some text was here <span class="hashtag">#share</span> <span class="hashtag">#repost</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btnRefresh">Refresh</button>
```

Вы создаете пустой массив `var posts = [];` и сразу же пытаетесь пройти по его элементам в цикле. Это, конечно, неправильно. Первым аргументом анонимной функции (являющейся вторым параметром `jQuery.get`) будут данные, полученные в результате запроса:

```
$.get("twitor.php?action=last", function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    var posts = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var newPost = addNewPost(data[i].name, data[i].text, data[i].date);
       posts.push(newPost);
    }
    divs.children().remove();
    divs.append(posts);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Тогда выводится бесконечное количество родительских элементов а не данных из бд =(

Comment: @ВикторДоценко - Вы не привели код функции `addNewPost`, так что мне нечего сказать по этому поводу.

Comment: так addNewPost добавляет в PHP вроде бы. Хорошо. Добавлю в верхний блок вывод функции этой.

Comment: @ВикторДоценко хорошо, давайте разбираться. Добавьте, пожалуйста, `console.log(data);`, как в моем коде, и посмотрите, что выводится в консоль.

Comment: спасибо вам за уделенное время. Просто хочется разобраться и понять что пошло не так в этом обучающем примере.

Comment: Я почему то не могу прикреплять ваше имя в начале сообщения

Comment: Ваш скрипт отрабатывается.

Comment: [Object, Object]0: Object1: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Как теперь все подвязать с $.get("twitor.php?action=last", function( data ) {

Comment: @ВикторДоценко - Нам надо понять, что приходит в обработчик `$.get` в виде аргумента `data`.  Прошу прощения, добавьте в вызов `console.log` `JSON.stringify`, как в моем коде.

Comment: Igor, В консоли выводится: "[{\"id\":\"61\",\"name\":\"454\",\"text\":\"454545\",\"date\":\"2016-04-22 18:14:34\"},{\"id\":\"60\",\"name\":\"we3r3\",\"text\":\"rfeef\",\"date\":\"2016-04-22 17:08:47\"},{\"id\":\"59\",\"name\":\"\\u0414\\u0436\\u043e\\u043d\\u0430\\u0442\\u0430\\u043d \\u041c\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441 \",\"text\":\"Jamie Vardy, \\u0437\\u0430 \\u0441\\u0443\\u043a\\u0443 \\u043e\\u0442\\u0432\\u0435\\u0442\\u0438\\u0448\\u044c!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\",\"date\":\"2016-04-22 16:11:45\"},

Comment: Igor, а сам скрипт каждую итерацию выводит одинаковый блок - Some text was here  и так бесконечное количество одинаковых блоков. Страница виснет))

Comment: @ВикторДоценко - Я добавил Ваши данные в мой пример кода - запустите и посмотрите - все работает.

Comment: @ВикторДоценко Да, еще. Попробуйте заменить `$.get` на `$.getJSON`.